Arrayformula and Sum in Google sheets
How do I make this formula into an ArrayFormula in google sheets..
=IF(A1="online", SUM(B1,C1,D1,E1,F1), B1)
I want the row number to change for each column in formula and then this formula to apply itself infinitely down the column
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A="online", SUM(B1:B, C1:C, D1:D, E1:E, F1:F), B1:B))
I have found that this will add together all cells from columns B, C, D,... and add them together rather use them as a range and take the cell's figure and add it to the other cells in the row.
Hope that make sense! Thanks in advanced!


You may try:
=byrow(B:F,lambda(Σ,if(indirect("A"&row(Σ))="online",sum(Σ),index(Σ,,1))))

OR
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="online", B:B+C:C+D:D+E:E+F:F, B:B))


Its as simple as that! Im shocked, thank you so much!!
Still trying to understand the the first line of code but the second one works perfectly! Thank you

Lets say you wish to do a sum of all columns from A-Z, its as simple as byrow(A:Z,lambda(x,sum(x))) instead of writing the whole A:A+B:B+C:C+....+Z:Z. do checkout byrow()

Ohhhh that makes a lot of sense! thank you for breaking that down for me !
